# Jenkins set a badge as a pre-build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm not sure I have terminology quite correct here, so I will try to explain as best as possible. I use Jenkins to run our Java automation. There are lots of long-running (2-10 hours) jobs executing constantly against different versions of the product under test. I need a way to look quickly at the Build History box of a job, and see which job is testing which product version.

I've used the Groovy Postbuild plugin successfully to add a badge (I think that is what it is) to the right of the build in the Build History Box. The actual groovy command is:

```
manager.addShortText(version, "grey", "white", "0px", "white")
```

The problem with this, is that it does not run until the build is complete. I need to do something like this before the build starts. (I will have access to the version pre-build, as it is passed in as a parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the Groovy Plugin (not groovy post-build) and execute a script as first action of your build (you need to use a system script in order to access Jenkins' classes.

Note however, that the `mananger` in groovy post build plugin is a shortcut, so you would need something like:

```
build.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createShortText(text));
```

## Update:

Since the above construct does not quite work, try:

```
 def action = new org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildAction(null, text);
 action.color = "grey";
 build.getActions().add(action);
```

Alternativly, you could just set the description:

```
build.description = text
```

Comment: Getting closer. I tried running this using the EnvInjectPlugin. I had to use currentBuild (instead of build), but it couldn't resolve GroovyPostBuildAction ... FATAL: No such property: GroovyPostbuildAction for class: Script1. Ideas?

Comment: Use the fully qualified class name for GroovyPostbuilAction: `org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuilAction`

Comment: Yes, I tried that already: `FATAL: No such property: org for class: Script1` I also tried `import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild`, but it produced a similar error.

Comment: `build.getActions()...` thing works for me if I import `org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuilActio‌​n`

Comment: Be sure to use step "Execute system Groovy script" and not "Execute Groovy script", as the second won't work and will fail with message "No such property: build for class: hudson" or alike

Comment: Or import the GroovyPostBuild library and create manager object something like this: ```import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildAction``` and 

```manager = new org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildRecorder.BadgeManager(build, null, null)``` see the API here: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/groovy-postbuild/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/groovypostbuild/GroovyPostbuildRecorder.BadgeManager.html