# How to write Jenkins console output to workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have searched over the internet and could not find any option to write the job's console output to a file in workspace. Could you someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a groovy system script or groovy post build step to gain access to the console output using `manager.build.logFile.text` (if post build groovy) or `build.logFile.text` if groovy system script.

Once you have that, you can write out the string to a file using either the standard File function (if everything is running on Jenkins master) or FilePath (if the job is running on a remote slave).

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514581/6606196) for an explanation of the FilePath class.