# Jenkins Pipeline: no permission to create directories inside script block with .execute()

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to run an external shell command (for example, `git clone`) inside a Jenkins pipeline.

I have found 2 ways of doing this.

---

This one works:

```
steps {
    sh "git clone --branch $BRANCH --depth 1 --no-single-branch $REMOTE $LOCAL
}
```

Downsides:

- I only see the output when the complete command is finished. Which is annoying if the command takes a long time.
- I need to do some Groovy scripting to look up values in a `Map`, based on parameters chosen by the user who starts the build. Haven't found a way to do that without a `script {}` block.
- A variation is to run a Bash script that runs the `git clone` command, that also works. Which will get me into trouble when running on Windows nodes.

---

The next one errors on

> fatal: could not create work tree dir 'localFolder'.: Permission denied

```
steps {
    script {
        def localFolder = new File(products[params.PRODUCT].local)
        if (!localFolder.exists()) {
            def gitCommand = 'git clone --branch ' + params.BRANCH + ' --depth 1 --no-single-branch ' + products[params.PRODUCT].remote + ' ' + localFolder
            runCommand(gitCommand)
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is the `runCommand()` wrapper:

```
def runCommand = { strList ->
    assert ( strList instanceof String ||
            ( strList instanceof List && strList.each{ it instanceof String } ) \
)
    def proc = strList.execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.out.close()
    proc.waitFor()

    print "[INFO] ( "
    if(strList instanceof List) {
        strList.each { print "${it} " }
    } else {
        print strList
    }
    println " )"

    if (proc.exitValue()) {
        println "gave the following error: "
        println "[ERROR] ${proc.getErrorStream()}"
    }
    assert !proc.exitValue()
}
```

---

My question is: how come I have permission to create directories when running a `sh` command, and how come I don't have that permission when I do the same thing inside a `script {}` block with `.execute()`?

I'm intentionally using the example of the `git clone` command to avoid getting answers that don't read the question, like using a `dir {}` block. If I can't create the git directory, then I can also not create the files inside that directory.

Comment: If you want to safely create directories, files etc., you need to use pipeline steps like `writeFile`, `readFile`, `fileExists` etc. All code like `new File(...)` gets executed on the master node only, not on the node that executes current stage and stores the workspace. More information here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233919/create-a-file-with-some-content-using-groovy-in-jenkins-pipeline/51234067#51234067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run any shell commands, use `sh` step, not Groovy's process execution. There is one main reason for that - any Groovy code you execute inside the `script` block, gets executed on the `master` node. And this is (probably) the reason you see this permission denied issue. The `sh` step executes on the expected node and thus creates a workspace there. And when you execute a Groovy code that is designed to create a folder in your workspace, it fails, because there is no workspace on a `master` node.

> *"1. Except for the steps themselves, all of the Pipeline logic, the Groovy conditionals, loops, etc execute on the master. Whether simple or complex! Even inside a `node` block!"*
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Source: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/01/pipeline-scalability-best-practice/#fundamentals</sup>

However, there is a solution to that. You can easily combine the `sh` step with the `script` block. There is no issue with using any of the existing Jenkins pipeline steps inside the `script` block. Consider the following example:

```groovy
steps {
    script {
        def localFolder = products[params.PRODUCT].local
        if (!fileExists(file: localFolder)) {
            sh 'git clone --branch ' + params.BRANCH + ' --depth 1 --no-single-branch ' + products[params.PRODUCT].remote + ' ' + localFolder
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this example uses [`fileExists`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace) and [`readFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) steps to check if file exists in the workspace, as well as to read its content. Using `new File(...)` won't work correctly when your workspace is shared between master and slave nodes.

If you want to safely create files in the workspace(s), use [`writeFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51233919/create-a-file-with-some-content-using-groovy-in-jenkins-pipeline/51234067#51234067) step to make sure that the file is created on the node that executes your pipeline's current stage.

Comment: I'm slowly starting to understand it.... turns out that `readFile` won't work, because of `java.io.IOException: Is a directory`. And is it possible that `fileExists` returns false when it's a directory? I'm currently going through the entire list of Pipeline steps to see if one exists that checks if a directory, not a file, exists, but haven't found one yet.

Comment: The `fileExists` step works for any type of files, including directories. Just double-checked that in one of my pipelines - it returns `true` for the folder that exists in the workspace.

Comment: Okay. But `readFile` definitely gives an `IOException` when used on a directory.

Comment: For this very specific use case, I decided to just use the `checkout scm` step wrapped inside a `script` block (to get the correct variables). It works, and I don't have to bother if the directory already exists or not. I'll tackle the problem of checking if a directory exists in a workspace when I encounter it again.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted, even though it wasn't the solution that I chose, it still explains my initial problem.

Comment: It was impossible to deduct from your question that you are looking for the equivalent of the `checkout scm` step. The `fileExists` step throws an exception for the file directories because it is designed to read contents from files. The directory has no content in that matter. Now I see more clearly what you tried to achieve, and in this case using `readFile` was not needed. Will update my answer to not confuse anyone.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to write the following code in another stage:
                        def doxyFile = 'doxyfile'
                        def doxyConfig = "OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = ../doxydocs_${PRODUCT}_${GIT_REFERENCE}"
                        if (fileExists(file: doxyFile)) {
                            doxyConfig = readFile(doxyFile).replaceAll(/OUTPUT_DIRECTORY *= .*/, doxyConfig)
                        }
                        writeFile file: doxyFile, text: doxyConfig
As you can see, I used `fileExists`, `readFile` and `writeFile`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to my problem:

- Don't bother with showing output as a command progresses, just deal with it that I will only see it at the end.
- Compose the entire command inside a `script {}` block.
- put a `sh` statement inside the `script {}` block.

Like this:

```
steps {
    script {
        def localFolder = new File(products[params.PRODUCT].local)
        if (!localFolder.exists()) {
            def gitCommand = 'git clone --branch ' + params.BRANCH + ' --depth 1 --no-single-branch ' + products[params.PRODUCT].remote + ' ' + localFolder
            sh gitCommand
        }
    }
}
```

This still doesn't answer my question about the permission issue, I would still like to know the root cause.