# How to create CODEOWNERS File using jenkins script under Workspace

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a question about How to create CODEOWNERS File using jenkins script under Workspace.

I was using this code to try to create CODEOWNERS file under Workspace directly.

```
fp = new FilePath(build.workspace, 'CODEOWNERS')
```

but it doesnt work

and the same question

Can I use

```
def String baseDir = "CODEOWNERS"
def dateien = findFiles(glob: baseDir)
```

becauese codeowners file has no type..

any solutions

Answer (score 0):

A [FilePath](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html) only represents a file *path* on a specific agent or the controller.
It does not in itself create any files.

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234067/6309), writing a file would be done directly in the workspace:

```
node {
    writeFile file: 'groovy1.txt', text: 'Working with files the Groovy way is easy.'
    sh 'ls -l groovy1.txt'
    sh 'cat groovy1.txt'
}
```

And [findFiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) should be able to look for files without "type" or extension.

Comment: Hi that means, I can use node to create CODEOWNERS file in the workspace?  node {
    writeFile file: 'CODEOWNERS', text: 'Working with files the Groovy way is easy.'
    sh 'ls -l CODEOWNERS'
    sh 'CODEOWNERS'
}

Comment: @user1938143 Yes, that is the idea. Give it a try for testing.

Comment: my gold is, I want to create a codeowners file in the workspace, and using findFiles to find all sub files, which are under sub folders, and get the contents and copy the contents to this Codeowners file

Comment: @user1938143 Sure. Start with the first step, and see if the codeowners is created where you want it to be.