# Jenkins: change the build history from different job

Tags: jenkins

I have two jenkins jobs:

- build the project
- deploy it

Both are working well and I can trigger the deploy job from the project build job.

Steps:

1. Build with parameters in the application's job >> check deploy on dev >> build
2. Add a yellow star badge to the build history in the application job - with groovy post-build action (code below)
3. Trigger the deploy job as post-build action

Question

4. After the deploy job was finished and failed change the build history of the application job (yellow star >> eg red one) - from the deploy job. How can I do that?

```
    if ("true".equals(manager.build.buildVariables.get('DEPLOY_ON_DEV'))) {
      manager.addBadge("star-gold.gif", "SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV")
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to develop but now it works like a charm in *Post-build Actions → Add post-build action → Groovy Postbuild → Groovy script*:

```java
import hudson.model.Build
import hudson.model.Cause
import hudson.model.Project
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.groovypostbuild.GroovyPostbuildAction

def log = manager.listener.logger
log.println('  ----------------')
log.println('  Groovy Postbuild')

// decorate this build
manager.addShortText('SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV', 'black', 'gold', '1px', 'black')
manager.addInfoBadge('SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV')
manager.addBadge('star-gold.png', 'SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV')

// decorate upstream builds
Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
List<Project> projects = jenkins.getAllItems(Project.class)

log.println("    This build: '${manager.build}' --> " + manager.build.getResult())
log.println('    Decorating the following upstream builds:')
//log.println(manager.build.getUpstreamBuilds())  // prints "[:]", so using this to get the upstream Builds doesn't work

for (Cause cause : manager.build.getCauses()) {
  for (Project project : projects) {
    if (cause.toString().contains(project.getName())) {
      int no = cause.getUpstreamBuild() 
      Build usb = project.getBuildByNumber(no)
      log.println("      ${usb}")

      usb.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createShortText(
          'SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV', 'black', 'gold', '1px', 'black'));
      usb.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createInfoBadge(
          'SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV'))
      usb.getActions().add(GroovyPostbuildAction.createBadge(
          'star-gold.png', 'SNAPSHOT deployed on DEV'))
      }
    } // for (projects)
  } // for (causes)

log.println('  ----------------')
```

Note:

This adds badges regardless of the build result but I'm confident that you can add the appropriate `if` easily. For removing badges see [Groovy Postbuild Plugin's page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin).

References:

- [Jenkins set a badge as a pre-build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563405/jenkins-set-a-badge-as-a-pre-build-step)
- [Jenkins main module 1.622 API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/index.html)
- [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)
- [GroovyPostbuildAction.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-postbuild-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/groovypostbuild/GroovyPostbuildAction.java)